# Deploy Controller Changes - Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: controller, deployment

My developer is on vacation, and I'm trying to deploy changes to a test class (TicketEditedTest) and I keep getting deploy failures:

Invoice_Thank_YouController.testInvoice_Thank_YouController Attempt to de-reference a null object
PreviewInvoiceController.test Attempt to de-reference a null object

These two controllers were in the org when I inherited it and the TicketEditedTest does not reference them in any way. The old controllers are referencing completely different objects. Why can't I deploy changes to TicketEditedTest?

```
private class TicketEditedTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        Campaign camp = new Campaign(Name='Test Method Campaign');
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name='Test Method Opportunity';
        opp.StageName='Closed Won';
        opp.CloseDate=system.today();

        insert camp;
        insert opp;

        sbxe1__Ticket__c newTicket = new sbxe1__Ticket__c();
        newTicket.sbxe1__sbx_FirstName__c = 'Test';
        newTicket.sbxe1__sbx_LastName__c = 'Ticket';
        newTicket.sbxe1__sbx_Email__c = 'test@email.com';        
        newTicket.sbxe1__sbx_Campaign__c = camp.Id;
        newTicket.sbxe1__sbx_Opportunity__c = opp.Id;
        newTicket.sbxe1__sbx_TicketType__c='Instructor Early Bird';

        insert newTicket;

        test.startTest();

        //update newTicket;

        List<sbxe1__Ticket__c> ticketList = [select tix.Id, tix.Name, tix.sbxe1__sbx_TicketType__c, tix.Attendee_Role__c from sbxe1__Ticket__c tix where tix.Id=:newTicket.Id];

        System.Assert((ticketList.size() == 1),
            'The test class found more than 1 ticket matching ticketID=' + newTicket.Id + ', size=' + ticketList.size());

        //sbxe1__Ticket__c updateTicket = ticketList[0];

        //System.Assert(((updateTicket.Attendee_Role__c == 'Instructor') || true),
            //'The test class Attendee Role was not Instructor when the Ticket Type was Instructor Early Bird. Role=' + updateTicket.Attendee_Role__c + ', Type=' + updateTicket.sbxe1__sbx_TicketType__c);

        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check sbxe1__Ticket__c object exist in ur org?

Comment: yes, it is there.

I checked the two controllers that are failing - their tests run fine

Comment: Did you try running all of your tests in sandbox, when you deploy to production all tests run, so something down the line may be causing other tests to fail.

Comment: @RavinSunkiller - Just confirming, you viewed the `Invoice_Thank_YouController` apex class and clicked run test, in production, and the test passed? Because if so, there is really no reason that it should fail just by deploying the new code. UNLESS - there is an updated version in the changeset that is being deployed and it does not pass.

Comment: @RavinSunkiller - Also, for reference, every test in your production instance is ran when you attempt to deploy new code. All tests must pass. That is why it is being run even though the class you are trying to deploy does not reference it.

Comment: I was able to enlist a developer friend, he discovered problems with methods in both classes that were causing issues. It doesn't make sense how the problems became problems because those classes have been in place since 2010 and haven't been touched.  Anyhow, thank you IRaj, Jenny B, and Eric for giving this some time. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enlist a developer friend, he discovered problems with methods in both classes that were causing issues. It doesn't make sense how the problems became problems because those classes have been in place since 2010 and haven't been touched.  Anyhow, thank you IRaj, Jenny B, and Eric for giving this some time. Happy New Year!